# calcular factorial en python usando el bucle for

Tags: python, bucle-for

necesito hacer el factorial de un numero entero usando el bucle for pero no se como, tengo este ejemplo pero no se en que estoy mal, estoy usando python 3.7

```
         def factorial (*n):
         for x in n:
         fact=1
         for y in range(1,x+1):
         fac=fac*y
         print ("fac")
```

Comment: corrige la indentación de tu código

Comment: Puedes resolverlo con un solo bucle, precisamente el segundo te puede servir. Si borras el primer `for` y reemplazas  `x` por `n` en el segundo. Luego ten en cuenta que estas imprimiendo una cadena "fac" , si quieres imprimir el valor de la variable `fac`. solo debes poner `print(fac)` .

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como lo tienes (arreglando ciertas cosas) es para calcular varios factoriales. Te pongo las correcciones a tu código:

```
def factorial(*n):
    for x in n:
        fact = 1
        for y in range(1, x + 1):
            fact *= y  # Como indica @César en los comentarios, puedes sustituir esta línea así
        print(fact)

factorial(1, 5, 3, 6)

# Devuelve
# 1
# 120
# 6
# 720
```

Es necesario corregir tanto la indentación como el nombre de las variables `fac` (ponerlas o todas `fac` o todas `fact`), por último, hay que cambiar en el print `'fac'` que es un string, por `fact` (variable)

**Factorial de un solo número**

Si solamente quieres el factorial de un número, puedes eliminar un bucle for como dice @Lucas Damian en los comentarios, quedando así:

```
def factorial(n):
    fact = 1
    for y in range(1, n + 1):
        fact *= y
    print(fact)

factorial(7)

# Devuelve
# 5040
```

Comment: También funciona con `fact *= y`

Comment: Cierto @César, lo había dejado tal cual estaba. Edito para incluirlo